# Fatal error: Class 'Prism\Database\TableImmutable'

Tags: joomla, fatal-error

I install the "itprism" component of joomla (crowdfunding compnent), and I have this error, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install itprism library http://itprism.com/free-joomla-extensions/others/software-development-kit.
Also look at the requirements to run itprism crowdfunding package here
http://itprism.com/help/95-crowdfunding-documentation-faq#requirements